# Finding the roots of the unknown function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, quadratics

> The graph of the function $f (x)$ is given.
>
> [image]
>
> How many different real roots does the $f (4-3x^2)=0$ equation have?

Here is possible solution:

> $$\Bigg [{4-3x^2=-2 \\ 4-3x^2=4} \Longrightarrow x=\left\{0,\sqrt 2,- \sqrt 2\right\} $$

Then, here is different solution:

> $$f(x)=x^2-2x-8$$
>
> $$f(4-3x^2)=0\Longrightarrow (4-3x^2)^2-2(4-3x^2)-8=0 \Longrightarrow 9x^4-18x^2=0 \Longrightarrow x=\left\{0,\sqrt 2,- \sqrt 2\right\} $$

> Problematic point.
>
> Here, I assumed the function is quadratic. But, obviously, this function may not be quadratic.

My questions:

- Question $-1:$ Is the first solution completely correct?
- Question $-2:$ Can we say that, the second solution is completely and definitely wrong? If so, is it possible to add something to this method and turn it into the right solution?

Comment: The first solution is OK. The second is wrong, because arbitrarily assumes an expression for $f$ that is not a datum of the problem, and also does not correspond to the graph.

Comment: @enzotib There is a discrepancy only in the right wing of the graph.  When we look at the graph on the computer for $x^2-2x-8$  , $f(x)$ looks like quadratic.

Comment: Yes, but given that there is no need to assume a particular form of the function, it is better to remain in the general case.

Comment: @enzotib hmm, You are right...

Comment: @Elementary: why is it "better" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know...Actually the story is like this.  A friend of mine sent the question to me.  And I sent the second solution to him.  Then he called me this nonsense.  And he sent the first solution to me..

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask this question to @enzotib. Your solution is clever, not at all nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: maybe I am wrong, but I think that in general, if you add an arbitrary hypothesis to a proof, you should verify that that hypothesis does not restrict the field of applicability of the proof, so this is a further work to do. If the hypothesis simplify the proof, that is good, but in this case the second method require more calculation than the first. Moreover, it is not immediate for all people to see that the second method cannot give a different result that the first.

Comment: @enzotib: the fact is that the given graph is irrelevant to the question, this is a kind of trap. Because we are not trying to mimic that function, we are trying to express two numbers by a single equation (a quite natural choice being the expression $(x+2)(x-4)=0$). This is the lesson to be drawn from this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are equally valid (and indeed give the same solutions).

The fact that the curve is not a parabola is irrelevant. What matters is that the function has exactly two roots, at $-2$ and $4$. In fact you are expressing that $x=-2\lor x=4$ in a single go.

Comment: Yes, this answer appealed to me.  Is it actually possible to prove this?  Regardless of the function, the result will not change.  Therefore, we can accept quadratic.  Maybe after our proof. Do you think there is a need to make proof?

Comment: @Elementary: not really. Any condition that is equivalent to $x=-2\lor x=4$, such as $|x-1|=3$, can do.

Comment: The solution is valid even if the function is not quadratic.  Is it possible to prove this idea a little?  In order to have no question marks in my head.  Would you like to add a few sentences?Because, I don't have a good math foundation..

Answer (score 0):

By way of illustration, here are a couple examples of functions $ \ f(x) \ $ which  are not quadratic and the results of the composition $ \ f(x) \circ (4-3x^2) \ \ . $

The first uses $$ \ f(x) \ = \ 1 - \frac{4}{\left(1 \ + \ \left(\frac{x-1}{3} \right)^2 \right)^2} \ \ , $$ which is itself a transformation of the function $  \ y  \ = \ \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)^2 } \ \ , $ altered so that it has zeroes at $ \ x = -2 \ $ and $ \ x = 4 \ \ . $  The graph displays $ \ f(x) \ $ in blue and the composition function in red; the composition, naturally, preserves the horizontal asymptote of $ \ f(x) \  \ . $

[image]

The second function is the polynomial $ \ f(x) \ = \ (x+2)^3 · (x-4)^5 \ \ , $ which is plainly constructed to have zeroes at the locations specified in the problem.  The vertical scale in the graph is highly compressed so that the function minima are visible.

[image]

Note that because the function $ \ 4 - 3x^2 \ $ has even symmetry, the composition $ \ f(x) \circ (4-3x^2) \ \   $ does as well, despite the lack of symmetry in $ \ f(x) \ $ itself.  It might also be mentioned that since $ \ 4 - 3x^2 \ = \ x \ $ for $ \ x = 1 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ -\frac43 \ \ , $ we have $ f(x) \ = \ f(4 - 3x^2) \ \ $ for those values of $ \ x \ $ .  This is particularly evident in the first graph; other intersections between the curves for $ \ f(x) \ $ and $ \ f(x) \circ (4-3x^2) \ \   $ depend upon the choice of function $ \ f(x) \ \ . $